# How to set different background color of every three html table rows in alternate

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have two HTML tables named table1 and table2. If I want to have different background of every alternative three rows of table2, how can I achieve that using CSS? For example set background of first 3 rows as blue, then another 3 rows as green, again another 3 rows as blue, again another 3 rows as green and so on. Basically I want two different background colors for every three rows in alternate. I found CSS styling for even and odd rows, or every nth rows, but not for this case. I have attached the screenshot of sample table. Rather than hard coding in individual row like in this code, I want to do it in CSS styling.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6k65.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "nth-child" to achieve this.

```
tr:nth-child(6n+1),
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: #dddddd;
}
```

Try with below snippet

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1px;
}
tr:nth-child(6n+1),
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Since this selects the table header as well, why not use 6n+2, 6n+3 and 6n+4

Comment: This is awesome buddy

Answer (score 1):

You want the alternative color for every three group of rows. Let explain the formula of css `tr:nth-child(6n+1),
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3)` where n=0,1,2,3......this `tr` selection will start from 1-3, 7-9....

Likewise `tr:nth-child(6n+4),
tr:nth-child(6n+5),
tr:nth-child(6n+6)` where n=0,1,2,3......this `tr` selection will start from 4-6, 10-12....

```css
tr:nth-child(6n+1),
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(6n+4),
tr:nth-child(6n+5),
tr:nth-child(6n+6) {
  background: green;
}

table {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now you will get alternative color of blue and green as your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for set the background-color

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
     $('#table1 tr').each((index, value) => {
         if(index % 3 != 0){
             value.css({'background-color': '#0000FF'});
         }else{
             value.css({'background-color': '#00FF00'});
         }
     });
});
```

or define two css class

```
.blue {background-color: #0000FF;}
.green {background-color: #00FF00;}
```

and assign this class in all tr of table you want

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the header and body and use **nth-child** concept

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+1),table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+2),table tbody 
tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
     background: #dddddd;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="table2">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
    <td >Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    .green{background-color:white;}
    .blue{background-color:gray;}
</style>
<script>

function alterColor(id){
        var table = document.getElementById(id);
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");    //get all the rows
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){               //alterColor styles         
            doalterColor(rows[i], i);

        }
}
function doalterColor(row, i){
if((i % 6 == 0) ||(i % 6 == 1)||(i % 6 == 2)){
        row.className = "blue";
    }else{
        row.className = "green";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="alterColor('mytable')">

<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 6</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 9</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 10</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 12</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>cell 13</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```